# How To Find Certain Days Between Two Dates Without DateTime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I should create a procedure that returns the number of selected days between
two dates. I mustn't use DateTime.
This procedure should take 7 parameters as (day1, month1, year1, day2, month2,
year2, desiredDays). The parameter “desiredDays” must be a list.

For example;

> - Given (1, 1, 1900, 25, 12, 2021, [“Saturday”]), it should output
>   “There are 6365 Saturdays.”
>   - Given (1, 1, 2020, 31, 12, 2020, [“Tuesday”, “Wednesday”]), it should output
>   “There are 52 tuesdays”
>   “There are 53 Wednesdays.”.

I've already found total days and I've written weekdays to a list. I divide total days into 7 to find how many weeks in it.  But I don't know how to find the selected day. Could you help me with it?

Here is my code:

```
    aylar = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
istenengunler = [ "Pazartesi" , "Sali" , "carsamba" , "persembe" , "cuma" , "cumartesi" , "pazar" ]

def artikyilsayici(a):
 
    yillar = a.y
    if (a.a <= 2):
        yillar -= 1
    cevap = int(yillar / 4)
    cevap -= int(yillar / 100)
    cevap += int(yillar / 400)
    return cevap
    
def hesapfarki(baslama, bitis):
    n1 = baslama.y * 365 + baslama.g
    
    for i in range(0, baslama.a - 1):
        n1 += aylar[i]
        
    n1 += artikyilsayici(baslama)
    n2 = bitis.y * 365 + bitis.g
    
    for i in range(0, bitis.a - 1):
        n2 += aylar[i]
    n2 += artikyilsayici(bitis)
    
    return (n2 - n1)
    
class Tarih:                         
   def _init_(self, gun, ay, yil, istenengun): 
     self.g = gun                           
     self.a = ay
     self.y = yil
     self.i = istenengun
     
tarih_1 = Tarih(1, 12, 1990, "cumartesi")
tarih_2 = Tarih(1, 12, 2021, "cumartesi")

farkgun=hesapfarki(tarih_1,tarih_2)
istenengun = farkgun/7
print(istenengun)
```

Comment: Use  [**`calendar`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html)

Comment: Does it have to work before October 1552? Because that was when the Gregorian Calendar was introduced. Are there any other complexities? Or should the code just assume a Western calendar which has always been in existence?

Comment: No no, it will be sufficient if it could work for after the 1900s

Comment: I meant 1582 not 1552, apologies.

Comment: Does it need to handle leap years correctly?